# Disable Coordinated-shutdown in akka

Tags: configuration, akka, akka-cluster

I'm trying to disable coordinated shutdown feature in Akka(2.5.3).
I added the configuration programmatically as below.

```
Config shutDownConfig =
ConfigFactory.parseString("{akka.coordinated-shutdown.terminate-actor-system = off\n akka.coordinated-shutdown.run-by-jvm-shutdown-hook = off\n akka.cluster.run-coordinated-shutdown-when-down = off}");
//Below is older configuration without shutdown props       
Config regular = userConfig.getConfig(actorSystemConfigPath).withFallback(userConfig);
Config combined = shutDownConfig.withFallback(regular);
actorSystem = ActorSystem.create(actorSystemName,combined );
```

The problem is Akka still tries to shutdown using CoordinatedShutdown and these
settings are not getting reflected in the actor system.

```
DEBUG 2018-07-10 15:27:11,388 [MACluster-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-18] akka.actor.CoordinatedShutdown - Performing phase [service-unbind] with [0] tasks
DEBUG 2018-07-10 15:27:11,391 [MACluster-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-18] akka.actor.CoordinatedShutdown - Performing phase [service-requests-done] with [0] tasks
```

I'm wondering if they are getting overridden by akka somewhere. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: is it disabled, when you add it to the config file?

Comment: I'm wondering a bit about the trailing `{` in the parsed config string. Sure that this is fine?

Comment: They are not getting disabled that's the problem. They are getting parsed correctly I don't think  `{` is the problem.

Comment: Okay. Repeating my first question. Is coordinated shutdown disabled, when you specify this config options in the config file?

Comment: No @StephenKing.As you can see from the Debug logs it's not getting disabled.

Answer (score 0):

akka.coordinated-shutdown.exit-jvm = off